# Why does spark-submit fail with "AnalysisException: kafka is not a valid Spark SQL Data Source"?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I use Spark 2.1.0 with Kafka 0.10.2.1.

I write a Spark application that reads datasets from a Kafka topic.

The code is as follows:

```java
package com.example;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;

public class MLP {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("MLP")
            .getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> df = spark
            .read()
            .format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092,localhost:9093")
            .option("subscribe", "resultsTopic")
            .load();
        df.show();
        spark.stop();
    }
}
```

My deployment script is as follows:

```
spark-submit \
  --verbose \
  --jars${echo /home/hduser1/spark/jars/*.jar | tr ' ' ',') \
  --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.10 \
  --class com.**** \
  --master (Spark Master URL) /path/to/jar
```

However I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
kafka is not a valid Spark SQL Data Source.;
```

I've tried using the same application with a non-Jafka data source and the dataframe is correctly created. I've also tried using yarn in client mode and I get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka as a Data Source for non-stream DataFrame - Datasets will be available from Spark 2.2, [reference in this issue on Spark](http://%20issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20036) JIRA

As @JacekLaskowski mentioned, change package to (modified Jacek's version to use 2.2):

```
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0
```

What's more, use `readStream` to read a stream of data.

You cannot use `show` with streaming data sources, instead use `console` format.

```
StreamingQuery query = df.writeStream()
  .outputMode("append")
  .format("console")
  .start();

query.awaitTermination();
```

[See this link](http://www.redsofa.ca/post/a_simple_spark_structured_streaming_example/)

Comment: I did not downvote you :(. I removed the df.show(); and included the query and included the exception to be thrown in main(). But now I get "Complete output mode not supported when there are no streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/Datasets ;; kafka" I have a Consumer set up which polls the topic and it exists.

Comment: @Suf You want to use streaming dataset or static? For static you must upgrade Spark to 2.2

Comment: Check `append` mode :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should replace `--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.10` (which I doubt works) with the following:

```
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.1
```

I don't think the version `2.10` was ever available. You may have thought about `2.1.0` that could have worked if you'd used `2.1.0` (not `2.10`).

Secondly, remove `--jars${echo /home/hduser1/spark/jars/*.jar | tr ' ' ',')` which Spark loads anyway except some additional jars like the one for Kafka source.

That should give you access to `kafka` source format.

Comment: In Spark 2.1 there is no Kafka source for non-streaming Datasets as far as I know

Comment: Yes, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20036. So partially your answer is correct, partially mine ;) However someone thinks my answer isn't correct o.O

Comment: Ouch. Right! Sorry for downvote. It **was** me. Fixed that.